# listview error after returning from child activity

Tags: java, android, listview, notifydatasetchanged

So, I have this rather interesting issue where I have this activity that holds a `ListView`. When I press the `ListView`, it goes starts another activity. once I go back to that parent activity though and I press on another item it crashes saying that I need to `notifyDatasetChanged`, I'm not sure where that should go, I though, thoughts?

```
public class StartEsole extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback, LocationListener {

    private GoogleMap mMap;
    LocationManager locationManager;
    ParseGeoPoint point;
    ListView listview;
    ArrayList<Details> businessList = new ArrayList<>();
    SwipeRefreshLayout mySwipeRefreshLayout;
    venueDetail vDetailAdapter;
    String userGender;
    int userAge;
    LocationManager mLocationManager;


    /**
     * ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
     * See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
     */
    private GoogleApiClient client;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        super.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_start_esole);
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
        locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.whatsLit);
        mySwipeRefreshLayout = (SwipeRefreshLayout) findViewById(R.id.swiperefresh);
        mySwipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(true);
        runHot();
        // ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
        // See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
        client = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this).addApi(AppIndex.API).build();
        //For The Adbanner-loads ads from admob
        AdView adView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.adView);
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
        adView.loadAd(adRequest);
        //FIY userFeed is VenueFeed
        listview.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), userFeed.class);
                startActivity(i);
                i.putExtra("venueName", businessList.get(position).name);
                startActivity(i);

            }
        });


        mySwipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(
                new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onRefresh() {
                        Log.i("AppInfo", "onRefresh called from SwipeRefreshLayout");
                        runHot();
                    }
                }

        );




    }
    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;
        LatLng home = new LatLng(getLocation().getLatitude(), getLocation().getLongitude());
        mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(home, 18));
    }


    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location curLocation) {
        mMap.clear();
        mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(curLocation.getLatitude(), curLocation.getLongitude()), 18));
        Log.i("AppInfo", "Location Changed");
        runHot();
        listview.setAdapter(vDetailAdapter);

    }


    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        try {
            locationManager.removeUpdates(this);
            checkLogic();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            e.getCause();
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {

    }


    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {

    }


    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {

    }


    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
        intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        startActivity(intent);
    }


       @Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    mLocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,1800000,0,this);
    mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
    mySwipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(true);
    vDetailAdapter = new venueDetail(StartEsole.this,businessList);
    vDetailAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    runHot();
}


    private void runHot() {
        mySwipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(true);
        aggregateTaskBars taskBars = new aggregateTaskBars();
        taskBars.execute();
        getLocation();
        checkLogic();
    }


    public Location getLocation() {
        mLocationManager = (LocationManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
        List<String> providers = mLocationManager.getProviders(true);
        Location bestLocation = null;
        for (String provider : providers) {
            Location l = mLocationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);
            if (l == null) {
                continue;
            }
            if (bestLocation == null || l.getAccuracy() < bestLocation.getAccuracy()) {
                bestLocation = l;
            }

        }

        try {
            assert bestLocation != null;
            point = new ParseGeoPoint(bestLocation.getLatitude(), bestLocation.getLongitude());
            //ParseQuery to update user activity on the serverside.
            final ParseObject userActivity = new ParseObject("UserActivity");
            ParseQuery<ParseObject> quserActivity = ParseQuery.getQuery("UserActivity");
            quserActivity.whereEqualTo("userId", ParseUser.getCurrentUser().getUsername());
            quserActivity.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
                @Override
                public void done(List<ParseObject> objects, ParseException e) {
                    if (e == null) {
                        if (objects.size() > 0) {
                            for (ParseObject object : objects) {
                                object.put("UserLocation", point);
                                object.saveInBackground();
                            }
                        }
                        if (objects.size() == 0) {
                            userActivity.put("UserLocation", point);
                            userActivity.put("userId", ParseUser.getCurrentUser().getUsername());
                            userActivity.saveInBackground();
                        }
                    } else {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            });

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return bestLocation;
    }


    public void checkLogic(){
        ParseQuery<ParseObject> qUserActivity = ParseQuery.getQuery("UserActivity");
        if(businessList.size()>0){
            if(Double.valueOf(businessList.get(0).adistance)<0.00189394){
                qUserActivity.whereEqualTo("userId",ParseUser.getCurrentUser().getUsername());
                try{
                    List<ParseObject>qReply = qUserActivity.find();
                    if(qReply.size()>0){
                        for(ParseObject object : qReply){
                            object.put("CurrentHotspot",businessList.get(0).name);
                            object.put("venueId",businessList.get(0).id);
                            object.saveInBackground();
                        }

                    }
                }catch(Exception e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }else if(Double.valueOf(businessList.get(0).adistance)>0.00189394){
                qUserActivity.whereEqualTo("userId",ParseUser.getCurrentUser().getUsername());
                try{
                    List<ParseObject>qReply = qUserActivity.find();
                    if(qReply.size()>0){
                        for(ParseObject object : qReply){
                            object.put("CurrentHotspot","None");
                            object.put("venueId","empty");
                            object.saveInBackground();
                        }

                    }
                }catch(Exception e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }

    }


    //For Set Map to the hottest place nearby
    public void startHeat(View view) {
        Log.i("App info", "Started Lit House");
    }


    //To get the GCD(math) to get a generic ratio between 2 numbers
    public int egcd(int a, int b) {
        if (a == 0)
            return b;

        while (b != 0) {
            if (a > b)
                a = a - b;
            else
                b = b - a;
        }

        return a;
    }


    public String truncateDistance(String x){
        Double dTempDist = Double.valueOf(x);
        if(dTempDist<1.0){
            //
            double feet =  dTempDist*(5280);
            x = "~"+String.valueOf((int)feet) + " ft";
        }
        else if(dTempDist>1){
            x="~"+String.valueOf(dTempDist.intValue()) + " mi";
        }
        return x;
    }

public class aggregateTaskBars extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
    ParseGeoPoint myPoint = new ParseGeoPoint(getLocation().getLatitude(), getLocation().getLongitude());
    public void downloadLocally() {
        downLoadTask nightClubDownload = new downLoadTask();
        nightClubDownload.execute("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=" + String.valueOf(getLocation().getLatitude()) + "," + String.valueOf(getLocation().getLongitude()) + "&rankby=distance" + "&types=" + "night_club" + "&sensor=true" + "&key=A");
        downLoadTask barDownload = new downLoadTask();
        barDownload.execute("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=" + String.valueOf(getLocation().getLatitude()) + "," + String.valueOf(getLocation().getLongitude()) + "&rankby=distance" + "&types=" + "bar" + "&sensor=true" + "&key=A");
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        //Query the user demographic for current user
        ParseQuery<ParseObject> userDemo = new ParseQuery<>("UserActivity");
        //Log.i("AppInfo",ParseUser.getCurrentUser().getUsername());
        userDemo.whereEqualTo("userId", ParseUser.getCurrentUser().getUsername());
        try{
            List<ParseObject> qReply=userDemo.find();
            userAge = qReply.get(0).getInt("Age");
            userGender = qReply.get(0).getString("Gender");
        }
        catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        //Query the bars
        ParseQuery<ParseObject> HotSpotBars = new ParseQuery<>("HotSpots");
        HotSpotBars.whereWithinMiles("venueLocation", myPoint, 10);
        try {
            List<ParseObject> qReply = HotSpotBars.find();
            if(qReply.size()>10){
                for(int i = 0; i<qReply.size();i++){
                    ParseGeoPoint myloc = new ParseGeoPoint(getLocation().getLatitude(),getLocation().getLongitude());
                    String sDistance = truncateDistance(String.valueOf(myloc.distanceInMilesTo(qReply.get(i).getParseGeoPoint("venueLocation"))));
                    String aDistance = String.valueOf(myloc.distanceInMilesTo(qReply.get(i).getParseGeoPoint("venueLocation")));
                    String venueName = qReply.get(i).getString("venue");
                    String id = qReply.get(i).getObjectId();
                    //TODO Create method to count total number of users
                    int count = queryCount(venueName,id,false,"",false);
                    String sCount="";
                    if(count ==0){
                        sCount="  Dead";}
                    if(count> 0 && count < 10){
                        sCount = " Nothing big";
                    }
                    if (count>=10 && count < 25){
                        sCount = " a little something";
                    }
                    if(count>=25 && count<50){
                        sCount = "May b a good one";
                    }
                    if(count>=50 && count< 70){
                        sCount = "  Packed";
                    }
                    if(count>=70){
                        sCount = "Its goin to b litt";
                    }


                    //TODO Create a method getGenderCount
                    int genderCountM = queryCount(venueName,id,true,"M",false);
                    int genderCountF = queryCount(venueName,id,true,"F",false);
                    int GCD = egcd(genderCountF,genderCountM);
                    String genderRatio="";
                    if(GCD == 0){
                         genderRatio = "Its dead";
                    }
                    else if (GCD>0){
                        genderRatio = String.valueOf(genderCountF/GCD)+" F :"+ String.valueOf(genderCountM/GCD)+" M";
                    }
                    Details newVenue = new Details(venueName,"Dist: "+sDistance, aDistance,"ageRange", genderRatio,sCount,count,id);
                    businessList.add(newVenue);

                }

            }
            else{
                //Log.i("AppInfo", "Downloading info... From Google API");
                downloadLocally();
            }
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }
    protected int queryCount(String name, String objectID, boolean onGender, String gender,boolean onAge){
        int total = 0;
        ParseQuery<ParseObject> qUserActivity=new ParseQuery<>("UserActivity");
        qUserActivity.whereEqualTo("CurrentHotspot",name);
        qUserActivity.whereEqualTo("venueId", objectID);
        if(onAge){
            //TODO work with breaking down agegroup

        }

        if(onGender){
            qUserActivity.whereEqualTo("Gender", gender);
        }

        try{
            List<ParseObject> qReply = qUserActivity.find();
            total = qReply.size();
        }catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        //Log.i("AppInfo",String.valueOf(total));
        return total;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
        super.onProgressUpdate(values);

    }


    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
        super.onPostExecute(s);
        mySwipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
        vDetailAdapter = new venueDetail(StartEsole.this,businessList);
        listview.setAdapter(vDetailAdapter);
    }
}
```

I know every time you add something to it... you need `notifyDatasetChanged`, but I'm not sure where it should go.

**I used this for reference:**
[notifyDataSetChanged example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3669325/notifydatasetchanged-example/5092426#5092426)

No luck yet, the error is as follows:

EDIT: Error and venueDetail class were requested.

```
08-27 01:00:54.215 15492-15492/com.esole.esole E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                             Process: com.esole.esole, PID: 15492
                                                             java.lang.IllegalStateException: The content of the adapter has changed but ListView did not receive a notification. Make sure the content of your adapter is not modified from a background thread, but only from the UI thread. Make sure your adapter calls notifyDataSetChanged() when its content changes. [in ListView(2131624124, class android.widget.ListView) with Adapter(class com.esole.esole.venueDetail)]
                                                                 at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1575)
                                                                 at android.widget.AbsListView.onTouchUp(AbsListView.java:4069)
                                                                 at android.widget.AbsListView.onTouchEvent(AbsListView.java:3820)
                                                                 at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:9297)
                                                                 at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2549)
                                                                 at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2240)
                                                                 at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2555)
                                                                 at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2254)
                                                                 at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2555)
                                                                 at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2254)
                                                                 at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2555)
                                                                 at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2254)
                                                                 at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2555)
                                                                 at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2254)
                                                                 at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2555)
                                                                 at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2254)
                                                                 at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2555)
                                                                 at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2254)
                                                                 at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2445)
                                                                 at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent_aroundBody0(PhoneWindow.java:1756)
                                                                 at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow$AjcClosure1.run(PhoneWindow.java:1)
                                                                 at android.view.PhoneWindowAO.ajc$around$android_view_PhoneWindowAO$2$99ce526bproceed(PhoneWindowAO.aj:113)
                                                                 at android.view.PhoneWindowAO.ajc$around$android_view_PhoneWindowAO$2$99ce526b(PhoneWindowAO.aj:117)
                                                                 at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1756)
                                                                 at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:2800)
                                                                 at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2406)
                                                                 at android.view.View.dispatchPointerEvent(View.java:9517)
                                                                 at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.processPointerEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:4309)
                                                                 at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.onProcess(ViewRootImpl.java:4175)
                                                                 at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3682)
                                                                 at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3735)
                                                                 at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3701)
                                                                 at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3709)
                                                                 at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3682)
                                                                 at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3735)
                                                                 at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3701)
                                                                 at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3828)
                                                                 at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3709)
                                                                 at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3885)
                                                                 at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3682)
                                                                 at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3735)
                                                                 at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3701)
                                                                 at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3709)
                                                                 at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3682)
                                                                 at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:6001)
                                                                 at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doProcessInputEvents(ViewRootImpl.java:5975)
                                                                at android.view.ViewRootImpl.enqueueInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:5936
```

venueDetail Class:

```
public class venueDetail extends ArrayAdapter<Details> {
public venueDetail(Context context, ArrayList<Details> venues) {
    super(context, 0,venues);
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent ){

    Details detail = getItem(position);
    if(convertView==null){
        convertView= LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.mylayout,parent,false);
    }
    TextView tvName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.venueName);
    TextView tvDistance = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textDistance);
    TextView tvAgeRange = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textAgeRange);
    TextView tvUserCount = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textUserCount);
    TextView tvGenderRatio = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textGenderRatio);
    tvName.setText(detail.name);
    tvDistance.setText(detail.sdistance);
    tvAgeRange.setText(detail.ageRange);
    tvUserCount.setText(detail.sCount);
    tvGenderRatio.setText(detail.genderRatio);
    //notifyDataSetChanged();



    return convertView;
}
```

}

Comment: I think you have not initialize your vDetailAdapter in onResume method

Comment: so you recommend I re-initialize in the onResume method?

Comment: Why u are clearing your adapter in onResume method?

Comment: Honestly, that was from testing, it shouldn't actually be there.

Comment: If you remove vDetailAdapter.clear();  listview.setAdapter(vDetailAdapter); in onResume method still you get error?

Comment: yes, it still persists

Comment: Currently onResume lookes like this:
`vDetailAdapter = new venueDetail(StartEsole.this,businessList);
        vDetailAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        lookForWhatsLit();`

Comment: Please add the error message to your question. You should add onResume() there too, not in the comments.

Comment: Sure thing, thank you.

Comment: You are seting adapter in aggregateTaskBars class than no need to initialize and write vDetailAdapter in onResume and onLocationChange

Comment: The error is clear. You need to call notifyDataSetChanged() in your adapter, which is an instance of venueDetail. Are you? Pleae add that class to your post, too.

Comment: sure thing, I didn't realize that the class needed that call.

Comment: I tried to add notifyDataSetChanged() to the class venueDetail, which didn't work

Comment: bear in mind it works the first time, its after selecting an item from the list (child activity) and returning to the listview (parent activity) and selecting another item from the list, that is where the crash occurs.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the problem, the problem is that when I ran the on resume method, it run a request location update, which in turn would run the onLocationChanged, this meant every time the GPS location changed it would run the task in the background, constantly adding items to a list, which meant that it would need to run notifyDataSetChanged(). I just commented out the runhot method call here

```
    @Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location curLocation) {
    mMap.clear();
    mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
    mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(curLocation.getLatitude(), curLocation.getLongitude()), 18));
    Log.i("AppInfo", "Location Changed");
    //runHot();
    listview.setAdapter(vDetailAdapter);

}
```